# well balanced and correctly written expression

Tags: c, algorithm, stack

i have a string  (char *ch) with parenthesis and i have to:

1) verify if the string is correctly written and well balanced, for example: "(())" is correctlly written and well balanced while ")()" is neither well written nor well balanced

2) return the position of the first parenthesis that deviates from this rule if the string is not well written and not well balanced.

for the first question, it's okay. my code is as below:

```
int WBalanced(char *ch)
{
    stack p; int i;

 for (i=0; i<strlen(ch);i++) 
  {

    if(ch[i] == '(')
    {
        addStack(P, ch[i]);
    else if(ch[i] == ')') 
      {
        if(stackEmpty(P) == 0) 
            unstack(P);
        else
            return (0);
       }
     }
   }



 if(stackEmpty(P)==1) 
    return (0);
 else
    return (1);

}
```

but for the second question, i dont understand well the question. if my string is "(()", does the position is the position of the second parenthesis? and if my string is "(()(" what is the position of the deviated parenthesis?

thank you for the help

Comment: For `"(()("` its the same answer as the question is about finding position of first parenthesis which is deviating from the rule.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya what is the position of the deviated parenthesis please if my string is "(()(" thank you

Comment: If you have doubts about the meaning of an assignment, you should ask your professor or TA. We don't know what they mean either.

Comment: The position of first deviating parenthesis is 1 for `"(()("`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i think is 4, the last parenthesis !

Comment: Assuming that the Indexing starts a 0 in C, As per my logic the first one has a matching close at position 2 and the second one does not have matching close. That's how it is the first one to deviate from the rule.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes, you are right. can you help me for the implementation please?

Comment: What issue you are facing with the current code?

Comment: the cuurent code asnwer, only, the first question

Comment: Agree with rici. Ask your instructor what they mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Stack as an implementation for parenthesis balance check, the solution should be :

First, assuming the indexing starts from 0. Stack.top = -1 (indicates no parenthesis is inserted in the stack). We run our algorithm from 1st left parenthesis (index 0) to the end parenthesis. 
fault_index = -1 (used to print which parenthesis is faulty)

1. If '(' is encountered -> insert into stack. Stack.top += 1 and fault_index = index of this parenthesis in the given string (fault_index must be set only when Stack is empty before inserting this parenthesis)
2. If ')' is encountered -> remove '(' from stack. Stack.top -= 1.

We stop when either of this conditions occur and must take corresponding action :

1. When string is empty :

   a. If stack is empty -> String parenthesis were balanced.

   b. If stack is not empty -> Fault is at fault_index
2. When you encounter an additional ')' i.e. when stack is empty and got this parenthesis,  this index is fault_index.

Comment: @Constellation, For your given input "(()" here is how the code will execute : 

Initially Stack.top = -1 and fault_index = -1

Encountered ( -> Stack.top = 0 and as stack was empty , fault_index = 0(index of the char in string. ) . Push ( to stack 

Another (  -> Stack.top = 1 , fault_Index not updated as stack not empty . Push to stack. 

Encountered ) -> Stack.top decreased from 1 to 0. fault_index still 0 .

As string is empty -> and stack not empty . Fault is at fault_index = 0 .

Answer (score 1):

There are undoubtedly many ways to approach this, but lacking additional requirements, I would count nesting levels scanning left to right.  If the count becomes less than zero, point to that symbol as the cause.

If the end of string comes and the level is not zero, point to that place (probably) as incomplete expression.

Comment: Say the string is "((asd)asd". The offending `(` is the second character. How would he know that if he does what you suggest?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I would say in that case, the offending `(` is the *first* character, as that is the one that is not matched.  The second character is matched by the 6th...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes for the "((asd)asd" is the second parenthesis but how to implement that?

Comment: At the end, if the count is non-zero, return (the index of) the first parenthesis in the string, as that is the first one that is unbalanced (there may be more unbalanced ones after that, but the first one is unbalanced.

Comment: @ChrisDodd which count please? "if the count is non-zero"

Comment: There's only one count -- the count that you increment for every `(` and decrement for every `)`

Comment: @ChrisDodd if my string is "((()(" the position is 2? if i understand the meaning of the question

Comment: Valid suggestions all.  I figure pointing at the end of string and saying "missing ')'" is just as valid as saying the left side is unmatched is, to a human, the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers. the using of counter is not a bad idea but it may be functional in this case "(()" and not functional in this case "((()("... :(